# how to allocate the unallocated space of windows partition

Tags: gnome, partitioning

I have recently unallocated the windows partition in my pc to free the disk memory but i am not able to allocate the unallocated space made by deleting the windows partition this is a screenshot of Gparted editor which shows what i have done
[image]

how can i allocate the unallocated space created and then i would like merge that partition into ubuntu partition without eventually loosing the data present in ubuntu partition.

*edit

[image]

*edit2

[image]

edit4

[image]

edit 5

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me see if I can help you. First you need to know something about LiveCD and GParted.

When using the LiveCD/LiveDVD/LiveUSB, GParted will be installed by default, so there is no need to install it in the Live Medium. This is different if you are using an installed version of Ubuntu in which GParted will not be installed by default, so you can only use GParted right away from the Live Medium but you need to install it in Ubuntu if you are running Ubuntu from an already installed scenario.

With this in mind, run the LiveCD/USB of Ubuntu and open GParted. I assume you read the [Using GParted to remove windows partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36328/using-gparted-to-remove-windows-partition/36335?noredirect=1#comment659719_36335) on how to resize (Dragging the yellow bar for example). What we do now is, in your case, select the Locked partition inside the Extended partition (in your case sda5) as shown by the Gray KEY icon. Right click on it and select Unmount, Disable or any other option that appears that unlocks it.

After that, simply select the Extended Partition, right click on it and select Resize. you should be able to resize it this time.

I have made a video to help you along the way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1uPH2zgrxw

Looking at your EDIT 5, here are the steps you need to do to remove Windows 7 and be able to boot afterwards:

1. Delete the SDA1 partition and set the SDA5 to boot with the boot flag parameter
2. Boot from a Live CD and run boot repair as mentioned in [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) This will make sure you boot from your Linux partition AND remove windows 7 from the boot list

Comment: when i run update-grub commend in terminal windows7 is again seen i have added that screenshot to my question as edit 3

Comment: Here is a book I have written about Ubuntu and it covers this part in some detail: http://luisviloria.com/ubuntu-for-end-users/

Comment: have you found any solution for this now?

Comment: From what I can see, sda1 (The boot partition) is still active and holds the Windows 7 boot part. This is why it still shows in the grub menu. I would recommend deleting that one but since it is the boot one, you would need to 1. Delete the sda1 partition and set the sda5 as boot with the boot flag parameter. 2. Boot from a Live CD and run boot repair. This will make sure you boot from your Linux partition AND remove windows 7 from the boot list.

Comment: is windows 7 holding any memory in my hard disk

Comment: Yes, you can see from gparted that it has 100MB, which is a reserved partition for the boot part of Windows 7. I have updated my answer to include the steps to remove Windows 7 and be able to boot from Ubuntu.

Comment: i have deleted that partition and and is full disk memory available for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I saw this same question just a couple of days ago....

/dev/sda3 is an extended partition - to gain accesses to the unallocated space, /dev/sda3 has to include it first.  To do this, boot from a live USB.

Install gparted on the live USB `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Use gparted to expand the size of /dev/sda3 to include the unallocated space.

Use gparted to expand the partition /dev/sda5 into the unallocated space which is now incorporated in /dev/sda3

Shutdown your computer, remove the USB, and startup again

Comment: can we do the same thing with a live cd

Comment: Exaclty.  I just get tired of writing "Live USB / Live CD"

Comment: Gparted is already included in Ubuntu, no need to install, just launch it.

Comment: @CharlesGreen i am currently on live cd and i dont know how to resize it can you help me for that

Comment: @user300458 can you guide me to resize the partition

Comment: the option of resize is not available for that partition

Comment: You should resize /dev/sda3 first, from LiveCD.

Comment: @user300458 yes i am not getting the option to resize i will add the screen shot now wait for a while

Comment: it's strange... press Alt+F2, enter `gksudo gparted` and try again: right-click on /dev/sda3, and then "Resize/Move"...

Comment: It looks very much as though you may have right-clicked on the unallocated space to get the context menu, rather than the /dev/sda3 line.

Comment: @user300458 i will try it now

Comment: @user300458 i cant do it again i have uploaded the screenshot of my faillure to my question

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes i did the same same now and the output is uploaded to the question

Comment: obviously, now you can resize it. :)