# Xubuntu 14 backup and reinstall or make /home folder

Tags: backup, home-directory, restore, unallocated

I am dual-booting win8 and xubuntu 14, but I only gave xubuntu 30gb space and decided to make it my primary os now.

I shrinked my windows volume and managed to free up around 300gb space.Now I would like to use this space to make a /home folder in Xubuntu and move my data there.

What could be the best solution to solve this? I would like to keep my xubuntu installed packages and configs so I would not have to start over.

Is it possible to make this 300gb space to /home partition under Xubuntu without
 reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible without reinstalling (or even rebooting for that matter).

First, you will need to create an empty ext4 partition in the free space, then move your `/home` there, and then modify a file called `/etc/fstab` to tell the system about your new home.

For detailed instructions, please follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).

Comment: Mind the "copy"; that needs to be "move".

Comment: But if I have a similar situation like shown here in the first picture: http://askubuntu.com/questions/492804/how-to-allocate-the-unallocated-space-of-windows-partition. Unallocated space is under /dev/sda for windows. Difference is that I do not want to actually merge the space to Xubuntu root partition but make a /home partition instead.

Comment: As I understand, you want your `/` and `/home` on different partitions, correct? Then you can follow the guide verbatim, without any issues. The two dirs are logically a part of the same tree but physically different. If you find it difficult to understand any particular step, or the reason behind it, feel free to ask.