# Stop cohabitation Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

it's been a while since I'm on Ubuntu and I find this OS much more convenient than Windows! That's why I decided to remove Windows completely my computer :) But I can not do it ... Before when I inserted the key booted with Ubuntu on it and that I chose when starting, it shows me several requests such as "Replace Windows with Ubuntu" (something like this). But since I can not and that's why I ask this question :) Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36328/using-gparted-to-remove-windows-partition

Comment: go, use the vmware OS migration tool and make a bootable image of your windows OS. Scale it down, and run it from inside linux. That is the best way, you dont have licensing issues, you dont need to reinstall in a VM, and all you files and settings will be as they were.