# How to have an existing Ubuntu installation overwrite a Windows partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, windows-10

I am getting used to Ubuntu 18.04, and when I first installed Ubuntu I set it so that I could still run windows 10. Now I want to switch to just be Ubuntu. I would like my Ubuntu partition to destroy my existing windows partition and expand so that my ubuntu partition is the size of both my existing windows partition & existing ubuntu partition.

While I would love to keep the existing file structure of Ubuntu, I do have a back up of the entire file system.

Comment: Have a look at `gparted`

Comment: I'd HIGHLY recommend keeping the Windows partition, as you'll need it to do some things that you can't do in Ubuntu... like BIOS or firmware updates, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using GParted to remove windows partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36328/using-gparted-to-remove-windows-partition)
This should explain how to do it using GParted. You just need to delete the windows partition in GParted before resizing the Linux partition, by right clicking on the windows partition and clicking "Delete"

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). If you have the reputation don’t forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!